# How do I loop through an array of objects without converting the objects to arrays?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8.80.0. I am trying to loop through an array of eloquent models but for `foreach` loop converts the objects to arrays. It works as expected if I use Tinkerwell but it does not when I try with actual components.

```
// Search for an application
$uuid = "123456";
$ra = new stdClass();
$ra->app = Application::uuid($uuid)->first();
// get the associated certificates as an array
$ra->certificates = $ra->app->review_certificates->all();

// Get the latest review
$review = $ra->app->reviews()->latest()->first();

// Create a test certificate 
$array = [];
$array['application_id'] = $ra->app->id;
$array['user_id'] = 1;
$array['area'] = 5;
$array['type'] = 2;
$cert = ReviewCertificate::make($array);
$ra->certificates[] = $cert;

// This works fine when testing using Tinkerwell
foreach($ra->certificates as $acert) {
  if($acert->exists) {
    echo "exists\n";
  } 
  else {
    echo "doesn't exist\n";
  }
}
```

The code that doesn't work.

```
class ReviewApplication extends Component
{
  public Application $app;
  public $certificates = [];

  public function mount($uuid, Request $request)
  {
    $this->app = Application::uuid($uuid)->first();
    $this->certificates = $this->app->review_certificates->all();
  }

  public function addCertificate($array)
  {
    $array['application_id'] = $this->app->id;
    $cert = ReviewCertificate::make($array);
    $this->certificates[] = $cert;

    $test = $this->certificates[ count($this->certificates) - 1 ];
    dd($test);  <--- this is an object
  }


  public function save() 
  {
    $test = $this->certificates[ count($this->certificates) - 1 ];
    dd($test);  <--- this is now an array

    $review = new Review;
    ... 
    $review->save();

    foreach($this->certificates as $cert) {
      if($cert->exists) {      <--- THIS FAILS
        // update
      }
      else {
        // save
        $review->certificates()->create($cert->toArray());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While in ReviewApplication component, existing certificates are loaded. The user can perform an action to create a new certificate. This is added to the array so that it can be displayed in the list of certificates (see `addCertificate`). The user then performs an action to save everything (see `save`). During save, I get the error `ERROR: Attempt to read property "exists" on array`. It seems that at some point, the objects in the array are converted from eloquent model objects to arrays.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you checked if its the whole collection that's casted to arrays or if it just affect the newly appended certs?

Comment: `dd($ra->certificates)` after `$this->certificates[] = $cert;` and share result.

Comment: I did. It seems that after `addCertificate` is called and before `save` is called, the array turns all of its elements into arrays. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

just use like below

```
if($cert['exists']) {      <--- THIS FAILS
    // update
  }
  else {
    // save
    $review->certificates()->create($cert->toArray());
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but that does not explain why the object is converted to an array.